# Calculus Derive $\tan 3x$ --> how does it become $3(\tan 3x)^2 + 3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Below is the solution to a math problem I'm working on.

> j) $f’(x) = 3\sec^2 3x = 3\tan^23x + 3$

I don't understand how the solution ended up as:

$$ = 3\tan^23x + 3$$

Comment: $\sec^2 x = \cdots$ in terms of $\tan^2 x$ ?

Comment: $\sec^2\theta = \tan^2\theta + 1$

Comment: Does the Chain rule ring a bell?

Comment: @Azif00 by your logic, shouldn't the answer be 3tan^2 3x+1 ?

Comment: @PineNuts0 $3(\tan^23x+1)=3\tan^23x+3$

Comment: Use chain rule of differentiation to solve this, you will get the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f'(x)=(\tan(3x))'=\sec^2(3x)\cdot3 $
(by chain rule)

$=(\tan^2(3x)+1)\cdot3$
,$(\sec^2(x)=\tan^2(x)+1)$

$=3\tan^2(3x)+3$

Answer (score 1):

There is a trigonometry equation $\sec^2{\theta}=1+\tan^2{\theta}$ which is applied directly to this